# Double grouping to find duplicates efficiently

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Suppose I want to find out the customers transactions for all customers who have used more than one currency.

eg, given the data

```
CustomerID CurrencyID   Amount
1000       1            100.00
1000       1            200.00
1001       2            100.00
1001       2            200.00
1002       1            100.00
1002       2            200.00
1002       2            100.00
1003       1            100.00
1003       2            200.00
```

I would like to get the results something like

```
1002
    1002       1            100.00
    1002       2            200.00
    1002       2            100.00
1003
    1003       1            100.00
    1003       2            200.00
```

I can get the results by using something like

```
(from r in CustomerTransactions
    group r by new { r.CustomerID, r.CurrencyID } into results
    group results by results.Key.CustomerID into results2
    where results2.Count() > 1
    select results2.ToArray().SelectMany(a=>a);
```

but this isn't efficient because it does multiple database queries.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

[linq](/questions/tagged/linq) is not really known for its efficiency.

I think if you could get the result to an `IEnumerable<T>`, it would be way faster!

```
IEnumerable<CustomerTransaction> results = db.ExecuteQuery<CustomerTransaction>
    (@" SELECT      CustomerID
                ,   CurrencyID
                ,   Amount
        FROM        CustomerTransactions    CT
        INNER JOIN  (
                        SELECT      CustomerID, COUNT(1) AS CurrencyCount
                        FROM        CustomerTransactions
                        GROUP BY    CustomerID
                        HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
                    )                       CT2 ON CT2.CustomerID = CT.CustomerID
    );
```

I assumed you have a class called `CustomerTransaction`. If you don't, you should use the correct `class` or use `dynamic` if the type is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I like using two nested dictionaries :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CurrencyID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1000, 1, 100.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1000,1,200.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1001,2,100.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1001,2,200.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1002,1,100.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1002,2,200.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1002,2,100.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1003,1,100.00});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1003,2,200.00});

           Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int, decimal>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("CustomerID"), y => y)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y
                       .GroupBy(a => a.Field<int>("CurrencyID"), b => b.Field<decimal>("Amount"))
                       .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.Sum(c => c)));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you missed the fact that the question was tagged linq-to-sql, but I don't see how this answer could apply efficiently to that scenario.

Comment: The dictionary is linq. I just used a datatable to test the linq.  If it is sql you can use a datadapter to put result into a datatable.